# Making a filename in a path dynamic

Tags: php

I'm trying to link to an image from a path in my dir.  How can I escape the variable properly?

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($images as $row) {
$config['source_image'] = '/assets/images/'.$row;
}
```

The $row variable needs to be in between single quotes.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need that?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Do you mean making it URL-safe? Check out urlencode(). You may also want to re-think your approach to using a foreach()-loop to assign a value to the same array index multiple times (only the last element in your array will be saved in 'source_image').

Comment: @roycable Oh yea, you're right.  I'm using code igniter's image manipulation library.  I want to be able to manipulate all the image files in my folder so I figured I'd iterate through all the filenames as $row.  But I'll need to rethink this approach now.  Thanks

Comment: This would write over `$config['source_image']` at each step of the loop. Additionally, you may want to do something like: `$config[] = rawurlencode('/assets/images/'.$row)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach ($images as $row) {

```
$config['source_image'] = '/assets/images/'.$row.';
```

}

Your code is perfectly fine the way it is tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
foreach($images as $i => $v){
  $config[$i] = rawurlencode("/assets/images/$v");
}
```

Now the `$config` array takes on the names or numbers, depending on the type of array `$images` is, of the `$images` array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use double quotes like the following.

```
foreach ($images as $row) {
   $config['source_image'] = "/assets/images/{$row}";
}
```

Or do you need it in single quotes?